# Discover any remaining apache logs

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

I am unfamiliar with Apache2 - I want to find out where the logs are going - I have this apache2.conf contents:

```
ServerName 0.0.0.0
ErrorLog /dev/stderr
TransferLog /dev/stdout
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog /dev/stderr
LogLevel warn 
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory "/*" >
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    #AllowOverride None
    #Require all denied
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-available/*.conf
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

and these `envvars`:

```
unset HOME
if [ "${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}" != "${APACHE_CONFDIR}" ] ; then
    SUFFIX="-${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}"
else
    SUFFIX=
fi
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
export LANG=C
. /etc/default/locale
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export NLTK_DATA=/nltk_data
```

does anyone know if any logs will be populated other than the logs in `/var/log/apache2/*`?

Answer (score 0):

`httpd -V` or `apache2ctl -V` will tell you the log locations in use, there are not more locations other than that.

You should know that:

- `/dev/stdout` is a special path that redirect everything you
  write to the standard out of the process
- `/dev/stderr` same as abobe but redirect to standard error of the
  process
- `/dev/null` same as abobe but instead of redirect, it just
  discards

Extra: The default apache2 logs location is not equal to every O.S. and in some of them `envvars` file don't exist.

Comment: ```apache2 -V``` will not respect ```envvars```